sed command is not replacing the files in my directory
When I run my bash script(given below) the files are not changed.  The replacement does not happen for some reason.  I am running the command as sudo, and the html folder has permssions 775 with the owner being my user.
#!/bin/bash

# Get the directory to search from the user
#read -p 'Enter the directory to search: ' directory
directory='/var/www/html/'

# Get the text to search for
search_text='Gavin'

# Get the replacement text
replace_text='dingus'

find "$directory" -type f -exec sed -i 's/$search_text/$replace_text/g' {} \;

# Print confirmation message
echo "Replaced '$search_text' with '$replace_text' in all files within '$directory'"

I have tried running the command as sudo and as my user.
I am expecting the file to change any occurrences of "Gavin" with "dingus" globally in all files in the /var/www/html directory.

This won't work because you are using single quote rather than double quote:
find "$directory" -type f -exec sed -i 's/$search_text/$replace_text/g' {} \;

This will search for $search_text, not Gavin.
This should work:
find "$directory" -type f -exec sed -i "s/$search_text/$replace_text/g" {} \;

Or
find "$directory" -type f -print0|xargs -r0 sed -i "s/$search_text/$replace_text/g"

